# A question on matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M\in\Bbb \{0,2\}^{n\times n}$ be a rank $t\leq n$ matrix and we know that it can be rewritten as $A+B$ where $A$ has $\{0,1\}$ entries and symmetric and $B$ has $\{-1,0,+1\}$  entries and skew symmetric. Are there any structured (meaning anything other than complex or real valued - like density of $\geq0$s) $L$ and $R$ ($L$ need not be $R^{-1}$) such that $LMR$ is a block diagonal matrix with $t\leq n$ blocks with each block of rank $1$?

Comment: If $t = n$, this means that $M$ diagonalizable. I don't think that's generally true for a matrix of this form.

Comment: $L$ need not be $R^{-1}$.

Comment: How are you defining "structured"?

Comment: Anything that can be additionally said other than $L,R$ are complex or real valued. Like density of positive values?

Comment: By "$A$ is $\{0,1\}$ symmetric" does that mean $A$ is symmetric and all of its entries are either $0$ or $1$? If so, since $M = A+B$ where $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is skew symmetric, we have $A = (M+M^T)/2$, which cannot have any entry equal to $1/2$. Hence, $M_{ij} = M_{ji}$ for all $i,j$, i.e. $M$ must be symmetric, which defeats the purpose of writing $M = A+B$. Let me know if I have the wrong interpretation of "$\{0,1\}$ symmetric" or if I made some other error.